# How do I put a text label on a google maps pin?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url-parameters

Google maps has changed their maps url parameters recently. There is a great rundown of how they work right [here](https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters).

I have a line of JavaScript that constructs a google maps URL and adds a label to the map. The old URL was:

https://www.google.com/maps?q=37.350544,-121.897047+(User+was+here+on+07/02/2015+at+10:15+AM)

The text under the pin is what is between the parenthesis after the latitude and longitude. This URL however, no longer works. I have exhausted every resource I know of. Including google documentation.

I would like to know how to add text to a google maps by putting that text in the URL. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/place/User+was+here+on+07/@37.350544,-121.897047,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0

I have a URL show a place but it not show marker, have you a idea??

Comment: Seems that adding label is no longer working. Maybe you want an alternate solution like using [**google map js api**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/). It's very simple to use actually. And for your problem, you can maybe just add a infowindow to your marker. Here's a really simple [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

Comment: As of 2018 this seems to be the closest to the original feature: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

It's not labels for any use but if you are trying to link to a place instead of a lat/lng this is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to pass text to the url that I can see right now with the new URL. I will try and work this API into or program. If anyone else needs to do this, google maps has an API that will allow text and the marker.

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label